# How to get filename in php in put request

Tags: php, put

I know we can read put request in file using

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

But how do i get the filename in the put request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filename is not sent as a part of the request. If you want to get the filename on the server side, you will have to pass it along by other means, i.e. query parameters.

Comment: so i cannot use PUT, I will have to use POST inorder to do that?

Comment: use PUT, but if you have an URL /upload.php, use /upload.php?filename=myfilename. Then you can extract it as $_GET['filename']

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PUT like in [PUT Method Support](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) page, you can get the filename they PUT to as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

For example, if I have the receiving PHP script

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$request_body = @file_get_contents('php://input'); 

error_log("Received PUT,  filename: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}, " . strlen($request_body) . " bytes");
?>
```

When I issue the CURL:

```
curl -X PUT -T "localfile.txt" http://example.com/interesting/target/name.txt
```

I get the output (in my error log)

```
Received PUT,  filename: interesting/target/name.txt, 4931 bytes
```

If you're asking how I could find out the name the file had back on the source file system (localfile.txt) I don't think that gets passed along.