# Upload and save file with original name

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

Do you know how to save a file that is being uploaded using the `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Below is what I have

```
public function upload_image()
{
    $str = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $filename = md5(time()) . '.jpg'; // I don't want to use this line
    $path = public_path() . '/uploads/' . $filename; // I want to use original file name here
    file_put_contents($path, $str);
    echo $filename;
}
```

Comment: You can get name by `$_FILES['name_of_input_tag']['name'])`

Comment: it's not being sent from an input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the file name with the form parameters since the file name is not 
sent by the request

You can check these answers

[How to get filename in php in put request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479386/how-to-get-filename-in-php-in-put-request)