# HTTP PUT request handler using go

Tags: go, put

Please consider this sample Go code snippet,

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        listen_at := ":3114"
        go http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
        //go http.Handle("/max", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))) <-- Fails
        go http.HandleFunc("/ping", ping_handler)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(listen_at, nil))

}

func ping_handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        a := time.Now()
        layout := "2006-01-02-03-04-05-000"

        fmt.Println("Got root!")
        fmt.Println("r is", r)
        fmt.Println("RemoteAddr is", r.RemoteAddr)
        send_this := "OK GOT ping! " + a.Format(layout)
        w.Write([]byte(send_this))
}
```

I've two questions:

(1) How can I change the FileServer to serve `/max` instead of `/` - my attempts failed, I get 404 for `http://localhost:3114/max/` and `http://localhost:3114/max`.

(2) I wish to accept `PUT` requests to `/max` - how can I achieve this?

Please point me the right direction, thanks!

**Edit 1**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        go http.HandleFunc("/ping", hello)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3114", nil))
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("STarting hello!")

        log.Println("Got connection")
        if r.URL.Path != "/ping" {
                http.Error(w, "404 not found", http.StatusNotFound)
                return
        }
        log.Println("Method:", r.Method)
        switch r.Method {
        case "GET":
                send_this := "OK GOT ping! "
                w.Write([]byte(send_this))
        case "PUT":
                fmt.Println("We got put!")
                err := r.ParseForm()
                checkErr(err)
                fmt.Println("r now", r)
                fmt.Println("r.Form", r.Form)
                fmt.Println("r.PostForm", r.PostForm)
        default:
                send_this := "Please dont!"
                w.Write([]byte(send_this))
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "Unknown request!")
        }

}

func checkErr(err error) {
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error", err)
        }
}
```

I send a PUT request as `curl -k http://localhost:3114/ping -T /tmp/a.go  -v`, it shows:

```
STarting hello!
2019/06/07 15:05:10 Got connection
2019/06/07 15:05:10 Method: PUT
We got put!
r now &{PUT /ping HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Length:[10115] Expect:[100-continue] User-Agent:[curl/7.47.0] Accept:[*/*]] 0xc4200ec2e0 <nil> 10115 [] false localhost:3114 map[] map[] <nil> map[] 127.0.0.1:64612 /ping <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc42005e340}
r.Form map[]
r.PostForm map[]
```

How can I find the actual data, and the filename that came in from PUT?

Comment: Use `/max/` instead of `/max` and you may also need to use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix depending on what files you expect. No need to use `go http.HandleFunc`, just call `http.HandleFunc`. For handling PUT requests differently from the fileserver, use a custom handler that calls the fileserver handler when method is not PUT.

Answer (score 2):

From https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux:

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or **rooted
>   subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash)**.

That means that `/max`, which is a *fixed rooted path*, will match only `/max` and the pattern `/max/`, which is a *rooted subtree*, will match `/max/`, any other path that starts with `/max/`, and by default it will also match `/max`.

```
http.Handle("/max/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
```

---

Depending on what the layout of your `.` directory is, you may need to use https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix.

Let's say your directory contains two files:

```
.
├── foo.txt
└── max
    └── bar.txt
```

Given the handler above, a request to `/max/bar.txt` will return the `bar.txt` file, but a request to `/max/foo.txt` or `/foo.txt` will return `404`, no file.

So if you want to serve the files from the `/max/` path, but your `.` directory doesn't have a `max` sub-directory then you can use `StripPrefix` to remove the `/max` prefix from the request's url path before it is passed on to the `FileServer`.

```
http.Handle("/max/", http.StripPrefix("/max/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
```

---

To handle `PUT` requests at the same route you need a custom handler.

```
type myhandler struct {
    fs http.Handler
}

func (h myhandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "PUT" {
        // business as usual
        h.fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        return
    }

    // handle PUT
    // ...
}
```

And then to register it, do:

```
fs := http.StripPrefix("/max/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
http.Handle("/max/", myhandler{fs: fs})
```

Comment: thank you. `// handle PUT` :  Please see **Edit 1** above - how can I find/retrieve actual data, and the filename that was inside the PUT request?

Comment: Apparently, filename is not sent as part of HTTP PUT request, it is often deduced from the URL `curl -k http://localhost:3114/ping/a.txt -T /tmp/a.txt  -v`  [helpful post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479386/how-to-get-filename-in-php-in-put-request)

Comment: If you want the filename with file send a multipart form and use the corresponding request methods to retrieve that info.